# Getting LNK2001 Unresolved external smymbol __forceCRTManifestCUR error

Tags: visual-c++

I am using VC++ 6.0 IDE for building and compiling my application.

I am getting error while compilation.
Error:- LNK2001 Unresolved external smymbol __forceCRTManifestCUR 
Fatal Error LNK 1120: 1 Unresolved external.

--------Version and configuration--------

- OS - Windows Server 2008 VC++ - 6.0
- installed on PC

--------Other installation are------

- Visual Studio 2008
- Microsoft SDk 5.0

Are

> C:\Program Files\MIcrosoft Visual
>   Studio\VC98\Include

and

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 9.0\VC\Include

Conflicting..

Please help in this issue..

Comment: Why, if you have VS2008, would you be using a 12-year old compiler and development environment? Why wouldn't you just use VS2008?

Comment: Did you check that you don't link libraries compiled with newer versions of Visual Studios?

Comment: Actually i have a very big application that is in vc 6.0.Now i need to run that application in VS2008 for my client.That why i am trying to do the compile in vc 6.0.   I opened the same code in VS2008 but in migration there is some bugs i found.Are is there any good migration tools which convert that easily...thanks